# Sqlite foreign keys cannot resolve error in android studio

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

can anyone work out what is wrong with this code? I'm getting cannot resolve error and both foreign key and references are in red.

```
   private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EXPENSES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXPENSES
        + " (" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_EXPENSES_SOURCE + " TEXT,"
        + COL_EXPENSES_AMOUNT + "NUMERIC," + COL_DATE + "DATE," + COL_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT," +
        COL_FOREIGN_KEY_CATEGORY + " INTEGER, "+ FOREIGN_KEY ("+COL_FOREIGN_KEY_CATEGORY+")
    REFERENCES "+DatabaseManager.TABLE_CATEGORY+"("+COL_ID+"));";
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was purely about adding spaces between some of the + and attributes.